# Extract coordinates from a polygon

Tags: graphics

I need to extract the coordinates from a `2D` polygon then calculate the maximum and minimum of the `x` and `y` coordinates. I know it sounds simple, but I've found it impossible to do so far. Below is my code:

```
a = Cases[poly, {_ , _}, Infinity];

coord = Table[{a[[x,1]]*1, a[[x,2]]*1}, {x, 1, Length[a], 1}];

Min[coord]
```

Where `poly` is a predefined polygon. The outcome of the `Min` function is this:

> ```
> A very large output was generated. Here is a sample of it. 
> Min[ -43.7405, <<143>>, 
>      Polygon[{{151.137, -34.062}, {151.137, -34.062}, {151.137, -34.0619}, <<14319>>,
>               {151.137, -34.0622}, {151.137, -34.0621}, {151.137, -34.062}}]]
> ```

The same thing happens if I leave out the line of code that uses `Table` to create `coord`, and instead just try to calculate the minimum of  `a`. This one has got me completely stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Ok here's the output of `FullForm[poly]`

> ```
> A very large output was generates. Here is a sample of it:
>
> List[ List[Polygon[  List[List[151.228, -33.956], List[151.228, -33.9561], 
>       List[151.226, -33.9563], <<976>>, List[151.229, -33.9559], 
>       List[151.228, -33.956], List[151.228, -33.956]]], <<1388>>, List[<<1>>]]
> ```

Comment: Since you created the polygon, then you must have its coordinates already? it helps to post a complete self contained example that shows the order of the operations, and not bits and pieces since that makes it hard to follow the logic.

Comment: You really need to consolidate everything into your question, i.e. get rid of those two pseudo-answers. Otherwise this thread will remain a mess.

Comment: It looks like your `poly` expression contains a list of length 2 at a higher level than the individual coordinate pairs that you are trying to reach with `Cases`. Try making the pattern inside `Cases` more specific, e.g. `{_Real, _Real}`

Answer (score 1):

It appears your data `poly` is not in the form you think it is.  So without a specific example at hand, I will give a fairly general solution, which is not hard to do.

- First extract each `Polygon` directive from the graphics data.
- Each `Polygon` may contain more than one polygon: separate them.
- Find the x and y bounds of each polygon.

For the graphics, I'll use the shape of Italy from `CountryData`.  It consists of three polygons.

```
bounds[coords_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Module[{x, y},
   {x, y} = Transpose[coords];
   {{Min[x], Max[x]}, {Min[y], Max[y]}}
   ];

italy = CountryData["Italy", "Shape"];

directives = Cases[italy, Polygon[pts_, ___] :> pts, Infinity]; (* strip any options *)
polygons = Cases[directives, _?(Depth[#] == 3 &), Infinity];
ranges = bounds /@ polygons
(*
   {{{-0.0763244, 0.0757934}, {-0.0848148, 0.0742848}},
    {{-0.0621578, -0.0398592}, {-0.067826, -0.0264755}},
    {{-0.00564986, 0.0386553}, {-0.107569, -0.0784857}}}
*)
```

Illustration:

```
Show[
 italy,
 Graphics[{Opacity[0.3],
   MapThread[{#1, EdgeForm[#1], Rectangle @@ Transpose@#2} &,
     {{Red, Yellow, Blue}, ranges}]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

The output of `Fullform` shows that your `poly` variable is not just a `Polygon` but is actually a list containing, among other things, the `Polygon`.

Even though `Graphics` is showing your `Polygon`, if you hover over the actual graphic I expect you'll see it complain:

> "... is not a Graphics primitive or directive".

To extract the `Polygon` and then the points, do this:

```
poly = poly[[1,1]];
points = poly[[1]];
```

To understand what I did above, you should read up on [Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Expressions.html), especially the tutorials.

As rasher hinted in his comment, you can get the minimum and maximum x- and y-coordinates as below:

```
{xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax} = {Min[points[[All, 1]]], 
  Max[points[[All, 1]]], Min[points[[All, 2]]], Max[points[[All, 2]]]}
```

There are more concise ways to do this, but I think this will be more understandable.